# JSHint supress var is already defined inside for

Tags: javascript, jshint

On the project I am working, there are a lot of code blocks like:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  //code 1
}
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
  //code 2
}
```

Can I disable the var is already defined warning only for this specific scenario?

There are files of > 10k lines, and to remove all vars and define at the top is not an option, unfortunately...

Any ideeas?

Comment: Global replace `for (var` with `for (let`?

Comment: cannot use let, it must be compatible with older browsers

Comment: it's a work project, 20+ persons on it... I just can't change all, it will create conflicts..

Comment: Its a very reasonable warning. If you don't want want to be told don't use JSHint - or do use it and try to educate the other 20+ people.

Comment: I agree it's a bit of a silly warning (not always but at least here). Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to exclude those specific things using rules. Even though ESLint has a better set of rules configuration, I don't think even that is capable of ignoring these. At best, you can put a `// jshint ignore:line` so it stops flagging them but you have to do it for each line again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no other solution than to replace from var to let, as @dfsq suggested in the comments.